# DispatcherTimer seems to be too slow

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer

I'm not sure if SO is the correct place for this kind of question. But, I will give it a try.

As it can be found all over the internet, using a `DispatcherTimer` for something like a countdown in `WPF`, seems to be the way to go. So I did.

My problem is, that the timer seems to be incorrect (too slow).

I check against the system-clock (so it's not 100% but close enough).

It figures out, that 1 minute system-clock is only about 58.5 seconds of the timer. When below 60s it's getting even worser.

The code (ViewModel):

```
private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Send, Application.Current.Dispatcher);

ctor(){
    _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    _timer.IsEnabled = false;
    _timer.Tick += TimerOnTick;
    _timer.Start();
}

private void TimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HandleTimeUpdateAsync();
}

private void HandleTimeUpdateAsync()
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        CurrentTime = _currentTime.Add(_currentTime < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) ? TimeSpan.FromMilliSeconds(-100) : TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
    }
}
```

`CurrentTime` is the property that fires the `OnPropertyChanged`-event for the formatted time that is displayed as 'mm:ss' (>60s) or 'ss.f' (<60s).

```
private TimeSpan _currentTime;
private TimeSpan CurrentTime
{
    get { return _currentTime; }
    set
    {
        if (_currentTime == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        // set timer-interval to 1/10 second when last minute
        if (value.TotalSeconds < 60 && _timer.Interval != new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100))
        {
            _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
        }

        _currentTime = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FormattedCurrentTime));
    }
}
```

I have no idea what I can do. Is there a bad mistake with the code that I don't see?

**Edit #1**

As by comments, the handling on each tick is more complex than in the code shown. It's not only updating the `CurrentTime` value.

Comment: Starting a Thread on every tick is a wasteful and basically wrong thing to do.

Comment: See my updated question. What would be a better alternative when I have to do much more than just updating a property on each tick?

Comment: A totally different question, not answerable frm this info. But probably still: do not use Threads.